# Adding web reference on client when using Net.TCP

Tags: .net, wcf, binding, reference, tcp

I am trying to using Net.TCP in my WCF Service, which is self hosted, when i try to add this service reference through web reference to my client, i am not able access the classes and methods of that service, can any have any idea to achieve this...
How I can add web references in this case. My Service has one method (GetNumber) that returns int.

### WebService:

```
public class WebService : IWebService
{
    public int GetNumber(int num)
    {
        return num + 1;
    }
}
```

---

### Service Contract code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int GetNumber(int num);
}
```

---

### WCF Service code:

```
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WebService));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWebService), new NetTcpBinding(), new Uri("net.tcp://" + Dns.GetHostName() + ":1255/WebService"));
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = long.MaxValue;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", Dns.GetHostName().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Opening Web Service...");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Web Service is running on port {0}",1255);
        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to EXIT");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

---

This works fine. Only problem is how to add references of this service in my client application. I just want to send number and to receive an answer.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the service's metadata (the description of you service) is not exported, that is why Visual Studio cannot create the proxy classes.

This [link](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/27/wcf-metadata/) explains how to export the service's metadata by changing the xml configuration file or directly in the code.

There is still a problem with the coded version of the solution presented in the link, which I explain below.

When executing the code presented, you get an exception saying

```
The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of
contracts implemented by the service M6.Servico.GetCurve.GetCrvService.
Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost
directly to enable support for this contract.
```

To fix this, I just changed the order things are done. First you create the behavior, set its properties and add it to the behaviors of the host. After that you add your endpoints, including the mexBinding

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
    typeof(MyService),
    new Uri("http://localhost:8080/MyService"),
    new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9000/MyService"));

ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior =
    new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);

host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(IMyService),
    new WSHttpBinding(),
    "");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(
        typeof(IMyService),
    new NetTcpBinding(),
    "");
Binding mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding();
host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(IMetadataExchange),
    mexBinding,
    "net.tcp://localhost:9000/MyService/mex");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client must have the proxy of your webservice as a class so it can instantiate it and use it to call your webservice methods.

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1) Is the service and client running on the same machine, if not is the firewall blocking communication?

2) Have you tried using svcutil to generate the client class (which you can then reference in your client application?

Answer (score 0):

just type in add service reference area of visual studio the base address of your configured net.tcp server ( visual studio does not discoveres tcp protocol-based servers automatically so you can point the address manually )